# Create directory if not exists else move file

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code to upload a file:

```
<?php
//set the image size in mb
$max_upload_size='10';
$MAXIMUM_FILESIZE = $max_upload_size * 1024 * 1024;
get_current_user();
global $current_user;
$uploaddir = './uploads/file/'.$current_user->user_login.'/'; 
$file = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['uploadfile']['name']); 
if ($_FILES['uploadfile']['size']<$MAXIMUM_FILESIZE) {
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'], $file)) { 
  echo "success"; 
} else {
    echo "error";
}
}else{
    echo"size_error";
}
?>
```

This works great if the user_login already exists under /uploads/file/ directory. How can I create the directory that is based on variable $current_user->user_login if it doesn't exists? If exists then continue on the next code.

Comment: i tried it but i can't get this to work. here's my sample code: `if(file_exists($uploaddir ) && is_dir($uploaddir )) {
 mkdir("./uploads/file/$current_user->user_login", 0777);
}`

Comment: Why -1? This is a valid question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php#105026:

> The destination directory must exist; move_uploaded_file() will not automatically create it for you.

Just use [`is_dir`](http://nz.php.net/is_dir) and [`mkdir`](http://nz.php.net/mkdir).

```
<?php
//set the image size in mb
$max_upload_size='10';
$MAXIMUM_FILESIZE = $max_upload_size * 1024 * 1024;
global $current_user;
$current_user = get_current_user();
$uploaddir = './uploads/file/'.$current_user->user_login.'/';
if (!is_dir($uploaddir) && !mkdir($uploaddir)){
  die("Error creating folder $uploaddir");
}
$file = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['uploadfile']['name']); 
if ($_FILES['uploadfile']['size']<$MAXIMUM_FILESIZE) {
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'], $file)) { 
  echo "success"; 
} else {
    echo "error";
}
}else{
    echo"size_error";
}
?>
```

Comment: is seems move_uploaded_file returns true but the folder is not created successfully.

Comment: Run this script. It may help. If the folder doesn't exist, it should give you a "Error creating folder" message.

Comment: may be it creates on different directory. but i don't know where it is. the full path is this based on my cPanel: public_html/wp-content/themes/my-theme/upload/uploads/file.

Comment: So your `$uploaddir` variable should be `./upload/uploads/file/`, maybe?

Comment: i don't think so because the code above is located under public_html/wp-content/themes/my-theme/upload folder named as upload-file.php. this file is being called by an ajax code like `action: '<?php echo UPLOAD; ?>/upload-file.php',`

Comment: When you run the code that I've provided, what response do you get?

Comment: i go deeper and this is the value of the `$uploaddir` variable: "./uploads/file//"

Comment: i believe the problem is not your code but the `$current_user->user_login` that is empty. i am using wordpress, btw.

Comment: oh yes, sure... just change this piece: `get_current_user();` for `$current_user = get_current_user();` and it should work. Also, put the line `global $current_user;` BEFORE this code. (I've updated my code to reflect this changes)

Comment: i tried it also to no avail. may be because upload-file.php is not part of the theme's file?

Comment: If this file is not being run by some wordpress controller/module, then you cannot retrieve the current user.

Comment: yes you are right. i tried this but doesn't work as well `if(!function_exists('wp_get_current_user')) {
    include(ABSPATH . "wp-includes/pluggable.php"); 
}`. any idea? also the correct function should be `wp_get_current_user()`. when i try it it returns an error `Call to undefined function wp_get_current_user()`

Comment: That's because you NEED to run that inside wordpress and not as a standalone script. Cannot help you on that. I suggest you to create another question specific for this issue.

Comment: but i am not sure if it is outside wordpress because that script is part of the theme. only it is being called using ajax when i upload a file.

Comment: If you call the file directly (e.g. /folder/file.php), then it isn't inside WP.

Comment: I'm no WP expert. Please open a new question now that we have figured ou the real issue.

Comment: I finally solved my problem by passing the value from ajax code to upload-file.php. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
  <?php
//set the image size in mb
$max_upload_size='10';
$MAXIMUM_FILESIZE = $max_upload_size * 1024 * 1024;
get_current_user();
global $current_user;
if(!is_dir('./uploads/file/'.$current_user->user_login))
{
   mkdir('./uploads/file/'.$current_user->user_login);
}
$uploaddir = './uploads/file/'.$current_user->user_login.'/'; 
$file = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['uploadfile']['name']); 
if ($_FILES['uploadfile']['size']<$MAXIMUM_FILESIZE) {
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'], $file)) { 
  echo "success"; 
} else {
    echo "error";
}
}else{
    echo"size_error";
}
    ?>
```

Or after $updloaddir initialization add if statement with $uploaddir parameter in `is_dir()` and `mkdir()`.